# How to get keyCode of character if SHIFT is used?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If a character is entered through keyboard using the **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key** then the **`keydown`** or **`keyup`** event only can trace the **`keyCode`** of **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key** i.e. 16.

Then how to trace the **`keyCode`** of the **character actually printed**?

I am using the following code-

```
onkeyup='alert(event.keyCode)';// Always shows a message 16(keyCode of SHIFT) irrespective of the actual character
```

or

```
onkeydown='alert(event.keyCode)';// Always shows a message 16(keyCode of SHIFT) irrespective of the actual character
```

Then how to get **`keyCode`** of the actual character printed???

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Comment: @Jeffman: Do you really think you have an answer to my question???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got the solution

I had to use **`onKeyPress`** event which **does not treat** <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> as keypress but ***the resultant character instead***.

Hence I can get the **`keyCode`** of the actual resultant character using **`onKeyPress`** event.

Syntax:

```
onkeypress='alert(event.keyCode)';
```

Now If I press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> it prompts the keyCode of <kbd>A</kbd> i.e. 65.

Comment: This doesn't work for symbols just as shift+1 should give you the exclamation mark.

Answer (score 29):

You can see the property `shiftKey` of the passed event object.

Take a look at this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SarH5/1)**

When you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> you can see the keyCode of it and `shiftKey` property `true`. Press any button together, i.e. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and the console outputs:

> 65
>   true

Which is the code of <kbd>A</kbd> and `shiftKey` property again.

Comment: resource **not useful**. Do you really have any solution in hand?

Comment: And useful for me, too - thanks! (I wonder if Rajesh Paul was aware you have to have the console open?)

Comment: @Velojet I think the actual reason why he didn't like that answer is because he used alert as an event handler. And alert was only printing the first pressed key (or something like that, I reproduced it once, but can't remember now)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative solution you can create a new event listener of keydown and create an if statement which holds `e.shiftKey` as boolean. If it returns true, nest a new if statement of `e.which` which will only return true for symbols and not for numbers.

```
input.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if(e.shiftKey)
    if(e.which == 52){
      // will only return the value of dollar sign ($) not a number 4
    }
})
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey